# Android Listview item click. how to implement back button on child activity

Tags: android, listview

Appreciate if some one can help.
I have a list view ("A") with about 6 items. When I click on any of the items, it opens up another activity ("B") and displays the item details.  I need to somehow allow user to go back to "A" from "B"
Whats the easiest way to implement this? is there a control that automatically does this for me. I know in IOS development, a navigation controller hooks all of this up without the programmer needing to write the back button code.

I am pretty new to android development

Comment: You are already going from "A" to "B" by clicking the list item. As for back, the back button does a decent job of this. Every device will have this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hardware back button on android phones will do this for you automatically.  Another way to handle going back is to use the up affordance (left carat) in the `ActionBar`.  You can enable this with [`ActionBar#setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)).

[image]
<sub>(source: [wptrafficanalyzer.in](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/actionbar_upnav.png))</sub>

Comment: oh I see what you are saying.  its true that the uses can use the build in back button on the phone.  is that common?

Comment: Yes it is very common and is the way you should assume users will handle going back.  I've edited my answer to give another solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you had created the new Activity with `startActivity` you just need to call `finish`. If you had spawned the new Activity by calling `startActivityForResults` then you need to call `setResult` and then finish in order to pass back data to the `onActivityResult` method of the prior Activity.